# What is the equivalent of mkinitcpio.conf on debian?

Tags: initramfs, initrd

I want to review that the hooks used to build the `initrd.img` are correct in my debian but I fail to find the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file like the one in Archlinux, what is the equivalent of this file in debian and how do I rebuild the initrd.img once I've edited that file ?

Answer (score 18):

To configure the initramfs in Debian, you can modify `/etc/initramfs/initramfs.conf`, or add configuration files and hooks to `/etc/initramfs/conf.d` and `/etc/initramfs/conf-hooks.d`.

To rebuild the initramfs, run `update-initramfs` as root with the appropriate options (`update-initramfs -u` to update the initramfs of the newest kernel).

All this is in the `initramfs-tools` and there are manpages documenting the various commands and configuration files.

Comment: In Debian 10 Buster are in: /etc/initramfs-tools/