# Unable to enable SMART support for external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd, smartctl, smart, smartmontools

I use my recently bought 1T Seagate Backup Plus Slim external hard disk `ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC` (NTFS filesystem) as a backup tool.
I want to run the Smartmontools software on this disk, but when I tried to enable it using

```
smartctl -s on -d scsi /dev/sdb (as a root)
```

I got the following response:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [i686-linux-4.15.0-23-generic] (local b$
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontoo$

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
Informational Exceptions (SMART) disabled
Temperature warning disabled
```

Indeed when I try to run for example

```
smartctl -all -d scsi /dev/sdb
```

the output is:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [i686-linux-4.15.0-23-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              BUP Slim WH
Revision:             0304
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        1.000.204.885.504 bytes [1,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x5000000000000001
Serial number:        NA9DTQ90
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Wed Jun 20 20:25:13 2018 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

which confirms that the SMART support is still disabled, but that is available. 
Does anyone have an idea if and (if so) how to enable it?

FYI: The drive is connected to an old 32-bit laptop that runs Lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Maybe related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637450/cannot-perform-smart-data-and-self-test-on-external-hard-drive

Comment: Thanks @AlvaroGutierrezPerez! It worked well, apart from rebuilding the initial ramdisk image. Instead of `mkinitcpio -p linux` I had to use `sudo update-initramfs -u` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268908/197569).

Comment: and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109065/575262).

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer, and even added more info I discovered recently about the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked this question on askubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/207573/how-to-enable-smart
If this fails, it could be that your USB enclosure doesn't support SMART,
I experienced this with one enclosure of mine. In that case you would need
to connect the drive directly via SATA or use a different enclosure to retrieve SMART data from the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to see in my BIOS whether SMART was enabled, but my computer hanged when I wanted to look at the external HD settings. However I have used SMART support before on this machine. When I ran `hdparm` I got this output: `Enabled Supported:  * SMART feature set, ...`, so that looks okay, but seems contradictory to the the fact that SMART support still is not enabled. Should I now attempt to specify the BUS (since i don't have problems with my disk, I don't want to open the enclosure)?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by "specifying the BUS"? It would be interesting to see the output of "smartctl --scan", particularly what kind of device your drive seems to be. The manual suggests that sometimes it could be useful for external enclosures to specify the type manually by "-d sat" or a different type, see "man smartmontools". Also, you could use smartmontools with "-x" instead of "-a" to get possibly even more information for debugging.

Comment: On the page https://askubuntu.com/questions/207573/how-to-enable-smart it is hinted at that details of the BUS connection could help establishing SMART support. The output of `smartctl --scan | grep sdb` is `/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device`. I just ran smartctl with only `-x` as an argument (so without `-d scsi`) and it showed that SMART now is enabled! I don't know what triggered it (maybe a software upgrade?)... B.t.w. It also works fine with `-a`.

Comment: Nice to see your problem is resolved now. Even though the cause of your problem seems to remain unknown. Maybe it will become clear at a later time.

Comment: I just found out that it seems to work when `smartctl --scan` indicates that the HDD is an SCSI device. For some reason it sometimes seems to erroneously display another device, but there's no problem after a reboot without unmounting the drive.